# Need code explanation Javascript for assigning a function to a constant

Tags: javascript, react-redux

Hi i have the following React-Redux based code snipped and dont understand the following line:

```
const List = connect(mapStateToProps)(ConnectedList);
```

I would understand that a function is assigned to the **List** constant if it would look like:

```
const List = connect(mapStateToProps);
```

But what effect has the **(ConnectedList)** in this statement and what is the technical name of that what happend?

---

Full Snipped:

```
import React from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return { articles: state.articles };
};
const ConnectedList = ({ articles }) => (
  <ul className="list-group list-group-flush">
    {articles.map(el => (
      <li className="list-group-item" key={el.id}>
        {el.title}
      </li>
    ))}
  </ul>
);
const List = connect(mapStateToProps)(ConnectedList);
export default List;
```

Comment: This article may be useful: https://www.sohamkamani.com/blog/2017/03/31/react-redux-connect-explained/#connect

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`connect(...)` returns a function (as you already realized), so `connect(...)(ConnectedList)` calls the function returned by `connect()` with `ConnectedList` as its argument.

The longer version of this would be:

```
const tmp = connect(mapStateToProps);
const List = tmp(ConnectedList);
```

---

Since you asked for the technical name: Usually a function returning another function is called a higher-order function.

Comment: Thx! That's exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

`connect(mapStateToProps);`

Returns a high order React component(HOC). In this case, connect will inject the state you are mapping on the mapStateToProps pure function.
The purpose of a HOC is to compose another component, that's why you need the second part:

`connect(mapStateToProps)(ConnectedList);`

The HOC returned by connect() will add the props to the ConnectedList component.

You can see the docs here: [connect documentation](https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#connectmapstatetoprops-mapdispatchtoprops-mergeprops-options)

Answer (score 1):

`connect()` return an higher-order-component (component that wraps a component).

This function is responsible to subscribe to changes in your application's redux store, and whenever a change in store detected, it will call the `mapStateToProps` function you provided, passing the new store state to that function.
The value returned from `mapStateToProps` will then be pass to the component you are wrapping as `props`.

This makes the components connected to the redux store, and hence the name of it.

By the way, I would name the component you are wrapping as `List`, and the component returned from the `connect()` function as the `ConnectedList`.